# Server 2008 R2 Group Policy Folder Redirects not working

Tags: windows-server-2008, redirection

I made a folder named `Folder Redirects` that is being shared by everyone with all but full control.

I went through the group policy for my domain and setup folder redirection. I applied the settings with `gpupdate /force`, then logged on as a user to test if the redirection is working.  There is nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You should post screenshots of the settings.  Also run a RSOP report to make sure the GOP is being applied to said accounts.

Also you should read the article here.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732275.aspx